# Unity3d 4.3 2d terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, terrain

I just started having a look at the new 2d tools for unity3d.
We can now use the native version of Box2d they have included.
I'm messing around using EdgeCollider2d and PolygonCollider2d to make terrain, I was just wondering is there now an easy way to apply a tiled texture to a polygon and get an effect like [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/99072-E2D-free-2D-terrain-editor-and-generator).
And if not can someone point me in the right direction on how you would normally do this.